# Prove (in an abstract setting) that a function is right differentiable and the right derivative is continuous

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, vectors

The following problem has appeared in the course of my research, as an attempt to apply my abstract theory to integral curves in a vector field $d$ as a practical application.

Let $\mathbb{R}^n$ be a finite dimensional euclidean space. Let $f:[0;1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ be a continuous function (so $f$ is a path). Let $d(x)$ be a non-zero $n$-vector for every $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ (so $d$ is a vector field).

Let us move to $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ space: function $g(t)=(t,f(t))$ and $e(t,x)=(1,d(x))$ for all $t\in\mathbb{R}$.

Let it is known that for every $t\in[0;1]$ and every $r>0$, $\phi>0$ we have some $\delta>0$ such that
$$\{ g(q)-g(t) \mid q\in]t;t+\delta[ \} \subseteq R((1,d(f(t))), \phi) \cap B_r(g(t)),$$
where $B_r(x)$ is the ball of radius $r$ with center $x$ and $R(p;\phi) = \{ v\in\mathbb{R}^{n+1} \mid \widehat{vp}<\phi,v\ne 0 \}$ is the cone of aperture $2\phi$ whose axis is pointed by the vector $p$.

a. Prove that $f$ is right-differenciable and the right side derivative is continuous. b. Is the above condition that $f$ is continuous necessary?

If it does not hold in general, does it hold for some particular "smooth" vector fields?

If you answer my question, I will thank you in my monograph (volume 2), which I am now writing.

Comment: Another similar conjecture: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1470877/another-conjecture-about-c1-integral-curves

Answer (score 0):

Counter-example:

Take $n=2$; $d(x,y) = (1,0)$ if $x<0$, $d(x,y) = (1,1)$ if $x\ge 0$; $f(t)=(2t-1,0)$ for $t\in[0;\frac12]$, $f(t)=\left(2(t-\frac12),2(t-\frac12)\right)$ for $t\in[\frac12;1]$.

Then $g(t)=(t,2t-1,0)$ for $t\in[0;\frac12]$, $g(t)=\left(t,2(t-\frac12),2(t-\frac12)\right)$ for $t\in[\frac12;1]$; $e(z,x,y) = (1,1,0)$ if $x<0$, $e(z,x,y) = (1,1,1)$ if $x\ge 0$.

Obviously the right derivatives of $f$ and $g$ are defined but not continuous. But the displayed formula in the question holds. Thus it is a counter-example.