# Another conjecture about $C^1$ integral curves

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, vectors

*I [had a research idea](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1470401/prove-in-an-abstract-setting-that-a-function-is-right-differentiable-and-the-r/1470621). However there was a [counterexample](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1470621/4876). In this question I present a similar but (seemingly) weaker conjecture to which that counter-example does not apply.*

Let $\mathbb{R}^n$ be a finite dimensional euclidean space. Let $f:[0;1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ be a continuous function (so $f$ is a path). Let $d(x)$ be a non-zero $n$-vector for every $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ (so $d$ is a vector field).

Let us move to $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ space: function $g(t)=(t,f(t))$ and $e(t,x)=(1,d(x))$ for all $t\in\mathbb{R}$.

Let it is known that for every $t\in[0;1]$ and every $r>0$, $\phi>0$ we have some $\delta>0$ such that
$$\{ g(q)-g(t) \mid q\in]t;t+\delta[ \} \subseteq R((1,d(f(t))), \phi) \cap B_r(g(t)),$$
and
$$\{ g(q)-g(t) \mid q\in]t-\delta;t[ \} \subseteq R((-1,-d(f(t))), \phi) \cap B_r(g(t)),$$
where $B_r(x)$ is the ball of radius $r$ with center $x$ and $R(p;\phi) = \{ v\in\mathbb{R}^{n+1} \mid \widehat{vp}<\phi,v\ne 0 \}$ is the cone of aperture $2\phi$ whose axis is pointed by the vector $p$.

a. Prove that $f$ is differenciable and the derivative is continuous (in other words prove that $f$ is a $C^1$-curve). b. Is the above condition that $f$ is continuous necessary?

If it does not hold in general, does it hold for some particular "smooth" vector fields?

If you answer my question positively, I will thank you in my monograph (volume 2), which I am now writing.

Comment: Probably we can build a counter-example based on $f(x) = \begin{cases}x^2\sin{(\tfrac{1}{x})} & \mbox{if }x \neq 0, \\ 0 &\mbox{if }x = 0\end{cases}$ from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothness

Answer (score 0):

Counter-example:

Let $n=1$.

Consider a function $f(t)$ with everywhere defined positive but non-continuous derivative $f'(t)$. For example $f(t) = \begin{cases}t^2\sin{(\tfrac{1}{t})+3t} & \mbox{if }t \neq 0, \\ 0 &\mbox{if }t = 0\end{cases}$ (based on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothness)) or any other function which has positive derivative but isn't $C^1$. Let $d(f(t)) = f'(t)$.

We have obviously $d(f(t))=\left(\begin{cases}-\mathord{\cos(\tfrac{1}{t})} + 2t\sin(\tfrac{1}{t})+3 & \mbox{if }t \neq 0, \\ 3 &\mbox{if }t = 0.\end{cases}\right) >0$ everywhere on $[0;1]$. Therefore $f$ is injective. Easy to see that $d$ is not continuous at $f(0)=0$ (take into account that $f(t)=3t+o(t)$ at $t=0$).

Let $g(t)=(t,f(t))$, $e(x)=(1,d(x))$.

$g'(t)=(1,f'(t))=(1,d(f(t)))$. Therefore
$$\{ g(q)-g(t) \mid q\in]t;t+\delta[ \} \subseteq R((1,d(f(t))), \phi) \cap B_r(g(t)),$$
similarly
$$\{ g(q)-g(t) \mid q\in]t-\delta;t[ \} \subseteq R((-1,-d(f(t))), \phi) \cap B_r(g(t)).$$